# Dificuldade em implementar tabuleiro de xadrez

Tags: c, loop

Preciso implementar o código que gere um tabuleiro de xadrez em ppm.
Seria no formato de 8x8 padrão, com a opção do usuário definir a quantidade pixels, a dúvida seria na hora de fazer o loop para "multiplicar" os pixels.
No código abaixo está saindo no padrão 8x8:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int larg, alt;
    larg = alt = 8;

    printf("P2\n");
    printf("%d\t%d\n", larg, alt);
    printf("255\n");

    int i, j;
    int tamanho = 2;

    for(i = 0; i < larg; i++){
        for( j = 0; j < alt; j++){
            if((i + j) %2 != 0){
                    printf("0\t");
            }
            else{
                    printf("255\t");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Espero que tenha ficado claro, e desde já peço desculpas por algum eventual erro, pois é minha primeira pergunta.

Comment: "um tabuleiro de xadrez em ppm" - O que significa esse *ppm* ?  E qual é a dificuldade em concreto que está a ter em concreto ? Que parte não está a ser feita/ não conseguiu fazer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro acho que você está desenhando o tabuleiro começando pelas colunas e não pelas linhas. Mas considerando que o tabuleiro é quadrado, isso não faria diferença...

```
for(i = 0; i < larg; i++){
    for(k = 0; k < tamanho; k++){
        for( j = 0; j < alt; j++){
            for(l = 0; l < tamanho; l++){
                if((i + j) %2 != 0){
                        printf("0\t");
                }
                else{
                        printf("255\t");
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Acredito que isso deve funcionar.

Comment: Deu certo sim! Muito obrigado.